# Python: function to group number by tens place

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement, logical-operators

Takes a list of numbers and groups the numbers by their tens place, giving every tens place it's own sublist.

ex:

```
$ group_by_10s([1, 10, 15, 20])
[[1], [10, 15], [20]]
$ group_by_10s([8, 12, 3, 17, 19, 24, 35, 50])
[[3, 8], [12, 17, 19], [24], [35], [], [50]]
```

my approach:

```
limiting = 10
ex_limiting = 0
result = []
for num in lst:
    row = []
    for num in lst:
        if num >= ex_limiting and num <= limiting:
            row.append(num)
            lst.remove(num)
    result.append(row)
    ex_limiting = limiting
    limiting += 10
```

But it returns [[1], [10, 20]]. 
What's wrong with my approach and how can I fix it?

Comment: You should not modify the list that is used for iteration.

Comment: I got it with DYZ's advice. thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may already have a correct answer, but here's an alternative solution:

```
def group_by_10s(mylist):
    result = []
    decade = -1
    for i in sorted(mylist):
        while i // 10 != decade:
            result.append([])
            decade += 1
        result[-1].append(i)
    return result

group_by_10s([8, 12, 3, 17, 19, 24, 35, 50])
#[[3, 8], [12, 17, 19], [24], [35], [], [50]]
```

It uses only plain Python, no extra modules.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
def group_by_10s(_d):
  d = sorted(_d)
  return [[c for c in d if c//10 == i] for i in range(min(_d)//10, (max(_d)//10)+1)]
```

---

```
print(group_by_10s([1, 10, 15, 20]))
print(group_by_10s([8, 12, 3, 17, 19, 24, 35, 50]))
print(group_by_10s(list(range(20))))
```

Output:

```
[[1], [10, 15], [20]]
[[3, 8], [12, 17, 19], [24], [35], [], [50]]
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Credit to advice for not iterating list during loop.
I got this answer at the end, for anyone who wants the answer. 
Thanks for support!

```
def group_by_10s(numbers):
  external_loop = int(max(numbers)/10)
  limiting = 10
  ex_limiting = 0
  result = []
  for external_loop_count in range(external_loop+1):
    row = []
    for num in numbers:
        if num >= ex_limiting and num < limiting:
            row.append(num)
            row.sort()
    result.append(row)
    ex_limiting = limiting
    limiting += 10
  return(result)
```

Comment: Please revise the accepted answers. Give it a little time, test all the answers out, and accept the one that is programmatically correct and that you found most useful.

Answer (score 0):

How about this one?

```
numbers = [8, 12, 3, 17, 19, 24, 35, 50]


def group_by_10s(numbers):
    arr = []
    for i in range((max(numbers) / 10) + 1):
        arr.append([])

    numbers.sort()

    for number in numbers:
        if number < 10:
            arr[0].append(number)
        else:
            index = number / 10
            arr[index].append(number)

    return arr


print group_by_10s(numbers)
# [[3, 8], [12, 17, 19], [24], [35], [], [50]]
```

Answer (score -1):

Do not modify the list while you are iterating over it, as when you remove items from it, some items get skipped over. Also change the bounds so that you will only append to `row` if `num < limiting`. I would add in a check to make sure the list has elements before adding it to `result`:

```
for num in lst:
    row = []
    for num in lst:
         if num >= ex_limiting and num < limiting:
             row.append(num)
    if len(row) > 0 :
        result.append(row)
    ex_limiting = limiting
    limiting += 10
```

This will yield:

```
[[1], [10, 15], [20]]
```

Comment: Thank you for giving me a tip about not iterating the object during loop. it solved my problem!

Comment: This does not produce the desired output for the second example: `[[8, 3], [12, 17, 19], [24], [35], [], [50], [], []]`. In fact, it always generates tons of empty lists. Try, e.g. `lst=list(range(20))`.

Comment: @DanielKim Apparently my answer is not up to snuff. If you could please unaccept my answer and accept one of the better answers I'd be appreciative :)

Comment: I appreciate your fairness.